# How can I draw a shadow for a path in canvas in jetpack compose

Tags: android, canvas, draw, android-jetpack-compose, shadow

I am drawing a custom shape for a topbar in jetpack compose.  I want to draw a shadow for the path.

```
 val topBarShapePath = Path().apply {
        moveTo(dpToPixels(leftPadding), 0f)
        lineTo(dpToPixels(leftPadding), dpToPixels(dpValue = 110.dp))
        arcTo(
                Rect(
                        dpToPixels(leftPadding),
                        dpToPixels(dpValue = 110.dp),
                        dpToPixels(dpValue = 32.dp),
                        dpToPixels(dpValue = 135.dp)
                ), -180f, -90f, true)
        lineTo(
                dpToPixels(dpValue = triangleStartX),
                dpToPixels(dpValue = rectHeight))
        lineTo(
                dpToPixels(dpValue = screenWidth),
                dpToPixels(dpValue = triangleEndY)
        )
        lineTo(dpToPixels(dpValue = screenWidth), 0f)
        lineTo(dpToPixels(dpValue = leftPadding), 0f)
    }
    
    Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(400.dp)
                    .drawBehind {
                        val finalWidth = 40.dp.toPx()
                        drawPath(
                                topBarShapePath,
                                color = topbarcolor)
                        drawOutline(
                            outline = Outline.Generic(
                                topBarShapePath),
                            brush = Brush.horizontalGradient(),
                            style = Stroke(
                                width = 1.dp.toPx(),
                            )
                        )
                    }
    )
```

This is the code I am using to draw the shape, the "drawOutline" was to try and draw a shadow for the path, but I can't figure out how to blur the line.

Any help appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the result I am looking for:
[image: Image of result]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's impossible to draw shadow in Canvas at the moment, but you can do it with `Modifier.shadow`, specifying the needed custom shape, like this:

```
class TopBarShape(/*some parameters*/): Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density,
    ) = Outline.Generic(Path().apply {
        // your path code
    })
}

Modifier.shadow(elevation = 10.dp, shape = TopBarShape(/*your parameters*/))
```

Sadly this modifier doesn't allow much modifications, [it's one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160665122) of the most starred Compose issues, so hopefully it'll change in future, but as it's not in the latest `1.1-beta` I wouldn't expect it at least until `1.2`.

If you still think that drawing shadow manually is a needed feature, you can [create a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128).