# Unable to change Elevation Color For Card in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I am using a `Card` in-order create different buttons.

I want my card to look exactly like shown in the image, and I tried many solutions online but none of that worked.

Just want to change Card elevation color, but can't find a way to do it.

```
Card(
            elevation = 4.dp,
            backgroundColor = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                Text("Subscription", fontWeight = FontWeight.W700, color = brc_red)
                Card(
                    backgroundColor = Color(0xFFBDFCBB).compositeOver(brc_green_color),
                    elevation = 6.dp,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(20.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            Toast
                                .makeText(context, "Suiiiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        }
                        .drawWithContent {
                            val paddingPx = with(density) { 5.dp.toPx() }
                            clipRect(
                                left = -paddingPx,
                                top = 0f,
                                right = size.width + paddingPx,
                                bottom = size.height + paddingPx,
                            ) {
                                this@drawWithContent.drawContent()
                            }
                        }
                    //   backgroundColor = Color(0xFF4CB849).compositeOver(brc_green_color)
                ) {
                    Row(
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Yearly")
                        Text(text = "$ 10 Per Year")
                    }
                }
                Card(
                    elevation = 6.dp,
                    backgroundColor = Color(0xFFFD6459).compositeOver(brc_green_color),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(20.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            Toast
                                .makeText(context, "Duiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        }
                        .drawWithContent {
                            val paddingPx = with(density) { 5.dp.toPx() }
                            clipRect(
                                left = -paddingPx,
                                top = 0f,
                                right = size.width + paddingPx,
                                bottom = size.height + paddingPx,
                            ) {
                                this@drawWithContent.drawContent()
                            }
                        },
                    ) {
                    Row(
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Monthly")
                        Text(text = "$ 1 Per Month")
                    }
                }
                Row(
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                ) {
                    Text(text = "OR", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
                }
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .clickable {
                            Toast
                                .makeText(context, "Nuiii", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        }
                        .padding(20.dp),
                    elevation = 4.dp,
                    backgroundColor = brc_green_color
                    //   backgroundColor = Color(0xFF4CB849).compositeOver(brc_green_color)
                ) {
                    Row(
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Start your 30 days Free Trail", color = Color.White)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[This is current Ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrqLA.png)

[This is what i want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjcNq.png)

Please guide me one this, it will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `spotColor` attribute of `Modifier's` `shadow` extension. You just have to make sure both the `shadow` and the `Card` have the same shape like having it instantiated outside, otherwise you'll end up having a sharp cornered `shadow`. You can also define the `Card's` `elevation` in the `shadow` without having the `Card` doing it.

```
 val cardShape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp)
    
 Card(
     modifier = Modifier
         .shadow(
             shape = cardShape,
             spotColor = Color.Green,
             elevation = 8.dp
         ),
     shape = cardShape
 ) { ... }
```

[image: Colored Shadow]

Comment: Thanks, This is the closest answer till but still I am not able to achieve desire results.
I am trying to use drawWithContent{ clipRect() {} } In order to get desired shadow and I just want to change The color clip effect. If i use shadow in My Card modifier that clipRect will fade away. Please read my existing code and let me know how can I achieve desired result. Thanks.

Comment: You're actually having a custom `shadow` by drawing something behind, not sure how would you color it, it, have you checked something that can incorporate a `color` with what you are drawing?

Comment: I have tried adding color but there is nothing that change the color of clipRect, I have checked the documentation and examples but none of that worked for me. Also I think clipRect is using default color and I am unable to change that color.

Comment: Have a look at this post about creating `shadow` manually
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70221549/how-can-i-draw-a-shadow-for-a-path-in-canvas-in-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `shadow` modifier. For instance:

```kotlin
Card(backgroundColor = Color.White,
     modifier = Modifier
         .fillMaxSize().padding(10.dp)
         .shadow(ambientColor = Color.Blue, elevation = 6.dp)
) {...}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution But it is creating white background behind my Card View. Also Color remains the same. Not working.

Comment: Also I have tried the exact same code in different project and I found that this code doesn't change elevation color, It removes the elevation. Please check.

Comment: I can't understand how it's not working, please see the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/draw/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).shadow(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color)) to check if you're writing it the right way.